# How to load xml file lists into listview from a folder in my android application

Tags: android, directory, storage

I have created a folder called "diagrams" in my application. In this folder there are xml files. What I would like to achieve is when I run my application those xml files will be populated in the listview. Basically my application package name is com.my.application.diagrams

I have tried to access the folder new File("/data/app/com.my.application.diagrams/");

it shows the directory but the xml files cannot be seen. If I put the xml files somewhere else  for example in sdcard and direct use the path /sdcard/ I can see the xml file list. Where should I place those xml files in my application and what path name I should use to access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your xml in Asset Directory or create folder under Assets and put it there.

> E.g
>         put your xml files in assets/simple.xml

To list files from Asset folder use following code

```
      try {
            String[] files = getAssets().list("");

            for (String fileName : files) {
                //Add this fileName in List
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I dont want to open the xml files at this stage. I only want to populate those xml files in the listview. I have coded the part how to populate files in the listview. I canpopulate files in the listview if the files in sdcard by pointing the directory as File("/sdcard/"). what I am wondering is what I should put instead of "sdcard" to direct my application in assest folder?

Comment: As I said I dont want to parse the xml file. I have lets say 5 different xml files in the folder. I want to populate those xml files in the listview then net stage when I choose any of them it will do something else. now I just want to populate those xml files in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the asset directory for your needs.  Android resources must be put into specific folder names.

Use the AssetManager to access them.

Comment: so I put the xml files in the assests folder. assests/diagrams/ myxmlfiles here.  so how to access there? what is the directory name?

Comment: The documentation for the AssetManager is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

the AM gives access to the assets folder and all that is put in there.

Comment: You may also want check out how to use the folder structure in an Android project for better performance and prevent crashes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html